# cumulocity smartrest template mqtt message not received

Tags: templates, cumulocity

I created a smartREST template via the frontend:

- templateCollectionId: mycid
- messgaeID: 456
- target rest api: EVENT
- Method: POST
- $.type: testType
- $ .text: testText
- $ .TIME: 2018-06-14 00:00
- rest api custom fields:
- testkey / string
- testValue / string

preview:

```
456 <TestKey>, <test value>
```

If I send the following message, nothing matters in the list of events (devicemanagement -> Events):

```
s/uc/mycid
456,halloKey,halloValue
```

could you help me?
Thank you

UPDATE:
I got the list of events via REST. There they appear. But why they do not appear on (frontend) under devicemanagement -> events and also on devicemanagement -> mydevice -> events?

**smartRule template**

[image]

Comment: This works for me. Are you sure that you created a device. Note that there is no automatic device creation if you are using custom templates.

Comment: yes, the device exist already. I can receive normal events (static events)

Comment: Try to subscribe to s/e to see what error is thrown when you send it

Comment: I tried it and I do not get an error message. How can I realize if my event has arrived? At the moment I'm looking under devicemanagement -> events. Is that correct?

Comment: Check the events in the device directly. Although of course it should also be in the global one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see the events also on the event list in "devicemanagement". They were always there, I had not seen them before because the $.time was set in the template in the past (see screenshot above). So the event entry was added to the list not at the top (as expected) but at some point below.
Thanks TryManuZ for the tip to check the bugs